# How to rename columns names in dynamically pivot table from other table?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables pointscategory and points:

```
    CREATE TABLE  pointcategory (
     categoryID int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     categoryname varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (categoryID)
    )
    CREATE TABLE points (
    pointID int(11) NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    value int(50) NOT NULL,
    categoryID int(10) NOT NULL,
    studentId int(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (pointID),
    FOREIGN  KEY (categoryID) REFERENCES pointcategory (categoryID)    )
```

I have created pivot table from points table by this procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_pivot`()
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
   SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'count(case when categoryID = ''',
      categoryID,
      ''' then value end) AS `',
      categoryID, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM  points;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT date(date), ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM points
                  GROUP BY date');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

The output is:
[image]
Now I want to rename the columns names (categoryId) in the above table by categoryname from pointscategory table.

> from date,1..6 to date,categoryname1 ... etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace `CategoryID` by `CategoryName` as column alias:

```
select group_concat(
           distinct 
               concat('count(case when categoryid = ''',
                      p.categoryid,
                      ''' then value end) AS ',
                      pt.categoryname
                     )
                   ) as cases
from   points p
join   pointcategory pt
on     pt.categoryid = p.categoryid;
```

```
count(case when categoryid = '1' then value end) AS cat1,
count(case when categoryid = '2' then value end) AS cat2,
count(case when categoryid = '3' then value end) AS cat3
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=77ea7a27965351102d7d1b60da0cfae3)*